# Django Page not found, The current path, didn't match any of these

Tags: python, django, url, url-pattern

I have created a new template in my app menus.html
The index path is working fine but when I added a new template that path is not working. Below is my url code in app

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    # url(r'^resto/menus/$', views.menus, name='menus')
    path('menu/', views.menus, name='menus'),
]
```

The path specified in first line is working fine. I want to add a new view to the path (views.menus)

Below is my urls.py from main app

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('resto/', include('resto.urls'))
]
```

My menus.html file

```
def menus(request):
    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

I tried restarting the server but not worked,
I am accessing this url `http://localhost:8000/menus/`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app (`resto` app) urls are wired to **`/resto/`** path and thus any path on your app will be prefixed with **`/resto/`**.

So, you need to call **`/resto/menu/`** to access the `views.menus` view.